# Retrieving font preference setting in Eclipse JDT plugin

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an Eclipse plugin which creates a `JavaSourceViewer` to visualize specific source code in a separate view.
I would like to configure the font of the viewer to match the settings of the *Java Editor Text Font* preference:

```
JavaSourceViewer textViewer = new JavaSourceViewer(...);
...

// get the SWT component which displays the text
StyledText textControl = textViewer.getTextWidget();

// retrieve the font preference from the theme manager
IThemeManager themeManager = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getThemeManager();
ITheme currentTheme = themeManager.getCurrentTheme();
FontRegistry fontRegistry = currentTheme.getFontRegistry();
Font font = fontRegistry.get(PreferenceConstants.EDITOR_TEXT_FONT);

// set the font on the SWT component
textControl.setFont(font);
```

My question is especially about the code block which retrieves the font from the theme manager:

- Is this the correct approach to get the font?
- Is there anything else which needs to be considered?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Eclipse plugin development, so just two minor notes after going through javadoc of the relevant APIs:

1. [`FontRegistry`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/resource/FontRegistry.html) has an `addListener` method which you might want and/or need to listen to and change the font of the `textControl` when the user changes their font settings.
2. The comment could be a great method name here (`retrieveFontPreference`, for example):

   > ```
   > // retrieve the font preference from the theme manager
   > IThemeManager themeManager = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getThemeManager();
   > ITheme currentTheme = themeManager.getCurrentTheme();
   > FontRegistry fontRegistry = currentTheme.getFontRegistry();
   > Font font = fontRegistry.get(PreferenceConstants.EDITOR_TEXT_FONT);
   > ```

   See also: *Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*, *Bad Comments*, p67: *Don’t Use a Comment When You Can Use a Function or a Variable*